# Attribute (align) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents

Tags: jquery, css, html, jsp-tags

I'm getting the following error while using the align attribute. 
How can I resolve this error with the appropriate HTML5 compatible syntax?

```
<table  align="center">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" id="username" autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="loginbutton" value="LOGIN" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="resetbutton" value="RESET"/></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: It would have been awesome if you had searched for this at all.  [Here](/questions/7108504/element-align-is-obsolete-or-non-standard-what-should-i-use-instead) is a 5 year old question that tells you how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the align attribute is deprecated in HTML5 and you can use it in this way and it will work,

```
<td style="text-align:right">
```

Comment: `align` is not deprecated, it is obsolete.  "Obsolete" and "deprecated" are different things.  Obsolete attributes may not work at all in a current release, whereas deprecated ones will still work but are not supported and may become obsolete in a future release

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of inline css.

```
<style>
.p {
    align-self:center
}
</style>

<table  class="p">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `center` align `table` with following

```
table
{ 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: style="text-align: center;" 
just this works fine :)